# creating an index for a join statement

Tags: mysql

I have a LEFT JOIN select statement that retrieves values from 2 tables: tableA and tableB. The syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT tableA.first, tableA.middle, tableA.last, tableB.full FROM tableA LEFT JOIN     
tableB ON tableB.full LIKE concat('%',tableA.middle,'%');
```

What is the best type of index to have for this statment? I've tried one on tableB.full but according to my EXPLAIN statement, it is not being used.

Note: though it's probably obvious, I am a newbie to join statements. 
thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

```
`field` LIKE '%foo'
```

cannot be optimized with index. You should avoid such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) it says:

> The following SELECT statements do not
>   use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE '%Patrick%';
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE other_col;
> ```
>
> In the first statement, the `LIKE`
>   value begins with a wildcard
>   character. In the second statement,
>   the `LIKE` value is not a constant.
>
> If you use `... LIKE '%string%'` and
>   `string` is longer than three
>   characters, MySQL uses the Turbo
>   Boyer-Moore algorithm to initialize
>   the pattern for the string and then
>   uses this pattern to perform the
>   search more quickly.

Unfortunately I don't know if in that case the Turbo Boyer-Moore algorithm can benefit from an index.